# Scrolling iframe on iOS causes the page to scroll

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iframe

I have an application that displays an iframe that the user needs to be able to scroll on an iPad.

Apparently you can't scroll iframes and other elements by default on iOS unless you use the special `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` in the CSS.

So for example I have the following HTML (based on David Walsh's solution here: http://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios)

```
<div class="frameContainer">
    <iframe src="./frame.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

html,
body
{
    height: 100%;
    background: #ff0000;
}

.frameContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 80px;
    right: 80px;
    bottom: 40px;

    background: #ffffff;

    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

    /* removes spacing below iframe */
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

.frameContainer iframe
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

However you can cause the page (red area) to bounce and lose focus of the iframe by either flicking the page (around the iframe) or by varying the speed at which you flick (e.g. dragging with your finger slowly). Or by tapping on the page around the iframe.

Demo here: http://preview.na-software.co.uk/Demo/ipadscroll/

I've tried some plugins like: http://www.hakoniemi.net/labs/nonbounce/ to prevent the page bounce, but because it's an iframe, it still causes the page to have a bounce effect when interacting with the frame because it's a different document level. I've also tried bubbling up the touch events from the iframe to the parent level so the plugin catches it, but the page can still bounce.